# How can I set this JQuery / Java Script Function to be activated on scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this function here:

```
  if($(".redacted").hasClass("redacted-animated")== false){
    $(".redacted").addClass("redacted-animated");
  }
}

function Uncover_Toggle(elem){
  if($(elem).hasClass("redacted-animated")== true){
    $(elem).removeClass("redacted-animated");
  }else{
    $(elem).addClass("redacted-animated");
  }
}

$(".redacted").on("click", function(event){
  Uncover_Toggle(event.target);
});

setTimeout(function(){Redact();},1000);
```

That along with this small piece of CSS:

```
.redacted {
-webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
box-shadow: inset -1000px 0 0 var(--color-dark);
transition: box-shadow 600ms cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);}
```

Adds small "Censorship Rectangles" to an HTML Text when the class of 'redacted" is used in a  tag:

[image]

It's currently triggered by a 1000ms Timeout.

`setTimeout(function(){Redact();},1000);`

I want to change this script to be triggered when the user scrolls, and tried to make it work like this:

```
    const $body = $('body');
    const $panel = $('.redacted');

    // Change 33% earlier than scroll position so the first redactions are there when the scroll arrives.

    const scroll = $window.scrollTop() + ($window.height() / 1.8);

    $panel.each(function () {
        const $this = $(this);

        // if position is within range of this panel.
        // So position of (position of top of div <= scroll position) && (position of bottom of div > scroll position).
        // Scroll was set to 33% earlier in scroll var.
        if ($this.position().top <= scroll && $this.position().top + $this.height() > scroll) {

            // Add class to currently active scroll position
            $span.addClass(`redacted-${$(this) )}`);
        }
    });
}).scroll();
```

But did not succeed - can someone point me to my mistake in triggering the script on scroll?

Comment: just like `click` you can write a `scroll` handler.  See [MDN scroll event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scroll_event)